# How I can get the AuthenticationContext to use the v2.0 endpoints?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, adal

I'm working on some code based on the onboarding sample code at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect.

I've registered the app at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ so that means I need to use the oauth v2.0 endpoints.

I've changed the initial sign-in request to use the /oauth2/v2.0/authorize endpoint which works, and fires the ProcessCode method in my controller. I get the code, id_token and state back.

Then in the ProcessCode controller action I am calling the AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync method.
This is going to /common/oauth2/token and returning 
"error":"invalid_grant",
"error_description":"AADSTS70000: Authentication failed: Authorization Code is malformed or invalid."

I'm guessing the is returned because the code was issued by the v2.0 endpoint and the aquire token request needs to go to the /common/oauth2/v2.0/token endpoint?

So question is any idea how I can get the AuthenticationContext to use the v2.0 endpoints? This has been driving me nuts for a few days now.

BTW using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory version 3.10.305231913

Thanks

Donal

Answer (score 1):

Use the Microsoft Authentication Library which is built to work with the v2.0 endpoint. You can find it here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client

In this library, the AuthenticationContext has been replaced with ConfidentialClientApplication and PublicClientApplication. In your case, since you're getting the token in your web server which is a confidential client, you'll need to do this:

```
scopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office.com/mail.read" }

var ctx = new ConfidentialClientApplication(clientId, redirectUri, clientCredential, tokenCache);
var t = await ctx.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(scopes, authorizationCode);
```

Replace scopes with whatever you want to get access to with the access token.
Keep in mind though that only a limited set of scopes are available in the v2.0 endpoint (mail, calendar & contacts from both the Outlook API and MS Graph).

**EDIT**
All scopes from the MS Graph are now available in the v2 endpoint.

Comment: Thanks Saca, will give it a try on Monday.

Comment: Hi Saca, a related question - after I get the code and id_token from the authorize call, how do I determine the current authorized user. I'm guessing by reading the Jwt token - but is there another way? Thanks Donal

Comment: from the code above, t.User will give you access to properties about the user. You should pivot of the UniqueId.